# Try to recall a book that describes the connection between languages, logic and mathematical foundation

Tags: reference-request

I remember there is a book published a few decades ago, which is probably hundreds of pages thick and  describes the connection between languages (nor sure formal or natural languages, probably latter), syntax, semantics, logic, and mathematical foundations (maybe set, type, or category theories). The first author is probably a women's name, such as Patty or not. I can't remember the book's name right now, probably like "languages, logic, and ....", and was wondering if anyone has seen the book.

Comment: Found it: Mathematical Methods in Linguistics (Studies in Linguistics and Philosophy, 30)
by Barbara B.H. Partee, A.G. ter Meulen, et al. | Apr 30, 1990

Comment: You should add that as an answer, not a comment, and then select it as the correct answer.